# C timestamp difference

Tags: c

Yes, i made revision of subject timestamp :) But there is something that i can't understand

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  time_t now = time(NULL);

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ("Current local time and date: %s \n", asctime (timeinfo) );
  printf("System time: %d",now);

  return 0;
}
```

After run i got:
Current local time and date: Fri May  3 09:17:07 2013

System time: 1367565427

But 1367565427 it's not 09:17 but 07:17:07

Why? I asked for my local - system time (which is now 09:17) with " time_t now = time(NULL); "
So how can i get my stetem time?

Answer (score 5):

Timestamp is in GMT, while localtime converts timestamp to your local time, so you seems to live in GMT +2.0 zone.

Comment: to be more exact, the unix timestamp is in UTC (without leap seconds). There's a small but important difference with GMT.

Comment: summarizing: i should add 7200 secounds each time to this value?

Comment: No, that's wrong since it will be different for each user's timezone. You should use localtime() to correctly convert timestamp to human-readable time.

Comment: yes i know it's different for users in differnet timezones. But i use in my C program and i  want to save the timestamp value in database. I still do not get how to display my timestamp, of my time, on my computer :)

Comment: Timestamp is one for all computers, and it is counted in UTC. You should store it as you get it. And, for each computer, upon displaying it, you'll need to call localtime or other functions which respect time zone.